# Finding average grade of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to write a function called, averageGrades, that takes in a dictionary with keys representing students and
values representing their grades. The function should return a new dictionary with keys representing students
and values representing an average of their grades. The average should be an int and should be truncated

I have managed to write a bit of code, that gives me one average value, but it doesn't iterate through the list...

```
def averageGrades(diction):
    avgDict = {}
    for k, v in diction.items():
        # v is the list of grades for student k
         avgDict[k] = sum(v)/ float(len(v))
         return avgDict
```

averageGrades({"Shana": [100, 90, 80], "Jody": [100, 70, 80, 90, 100], "Mike":
[100, 100, 20]})

When i do this ^ I get {'Shana': 90.0} when i want {'Jody': 88, 'Mike': 73, 'Shana': 90}

Comment: Don't `return avgDict` inside the loop; it will only include what it has processed up to that point (i.e. the first item).

Comment: Could you print `diction` keys and values?

Comment: @karl You should not change the content of any question. If you really want to delete then raise a flag/delete the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your return statement position is misplaced. In your case the return statement is inside the for loop, so return statement is returning dict with the first element, rather than the whole dict. Try the following code

```
def averageGrades(diction):
    avgDict = {}
    for k, v in diction.items():
        # v is the list of grades for student k
         avgDict[k] = sum(v)/ float(len(v))
    return avgDict
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
def averageGrades(diction):
    avgDict = {}
    for k, v in diction.items():
        # v is the list of grades for student k
         avgDict[k] = sum(v)/ float(len(v))
    return avgDict
    ^^^^^
```

Indentation is important.

Your function stopped at the first loop because the `return` statement was written before the `for` statement ended

Answer (score 0):

You should return your averageDict outside your for loop. If it is inside the for loop, return statement will return after the first iteration, which you don't want. Try as follows.

```
def averageGrades(diction):
    avgDict = {}
    for k, v in diction.items():
        # v is the list of grades for student k
         avgDict[k] = sum(v)/ float(len(v))
    return avgDict

print(averageGrades({"Shana": [100, 90, 80], "Jody": [100, 70, 80, 90, 100], "Mike": [100, 100, 20]}))
```